# In seaborn, how to turn off xaxis title, but keep xaxis labels and ticks?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to hide x axis title, but keep x axis ticks and tick labels. The only option that I have gotten to work is `ax.set_xlabel('')`. Is there an option to set x axis title's visibility alone to false? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single `ax` returned from a seaborn plotting function we can use `ax.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)`:

```py
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=df)
ax.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)
```

[image: Barplot with xaxis label removed]